# Why does df.at rise a KeyError with a MultiIndex while df.loc does not?

Tags: python, pandas, select, multi-index

I'm having issues with one of my functions after switching from a regular Index to a MultiIndex, and I'm not sure how to address this. Let me take the DataFrame from the pandas documentation for pandas.DataFrame.at to illustrate the problem:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [10, 20, 30]],
...                   index=[4, 5, 6], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> df
    A   B   C
4   0   2   3
5   0   4   1
6  10  20  30
>>> df.at[4, 'B']
2
```

If you now convert this into a MultiIndex, the same call will fail and raise a KeyError:

```
>>> df = df.set_index("A", append=True)
>>> df
       B   C
  A
4 0    2   3
5 0    4   1
6 10  20  30
>>> df.at[4, 'B']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    df.at[4, "B"]
     ~~~~~^^^^^^^^
  File "/.../pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2419, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.../pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2371, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.../pandas/core/frame.py", line 3882, in _get_value
    loc = engine.get_loc(index)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 822, in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEn
gine.get_loc
KeyError: 4
```

This kind of behavior would be fine, if loc was behaving in the same way - which it doesn't:

```
>>> df.loc[4, 'B']
A
0    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

You can get around this by specifying all levels of the index of course...

```
df.at[(4,0), 'B']
2
```

but given that I have quite a number of MultiIndex-levels that does not seem like an feasible solution. And using loc and then appending a .iloc[0] doesn't feel very pythonic either...
Does anybody know how to make .at work without specifying more than the first level?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve with the indexing ?

Comment: The indexes are used for a variety of grouping operations. In my use case I found it easier to use a MultiIndex instead of additional columns, but maybe that decision was subpar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) is designed to select a **single** value in a DataFrame.

> Access a single value for a row/column label pair.

Thus you must provide **all** indexers.

As you shown in your example, [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with an incomplete indexer yields a **Series**, not a value:

```
df.loc[4, 'B']

A
0    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

This wouldn't be compatible with `at`'s behavior of selecting a single value.

The `KeyError` is the result of an explicit check for a complete indexer:

See the code of [`pandas/core/frame.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py#L4183-L4186)

```
        # For MultiIndex going through engine effectively restricts us to
        #  same-length tuples; see test_get_set_value_no_partial_indexing
        loc = engine.get_loc(index)
        return series._values[loc]
```

Comment: I see your point, but pandas does not enforce the index to be unique, and if you (for whatever reason) have an index with duplicate values, df.at[duplicate_value] will actually return a series, just like loc.

Comment: @gunnar pandas does enforce this behavior. I added an excerpt of the source code.

Comment: Actually, if you have a duplicated index (e.g. using `index=[4, 4, 6]` in your constructor), then `df.at[(4,0), 'B']` should raise an error (`ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!`). Really, the design of `at` it to get/set a **single** value and the code has checks to ensure this is the case.

Comment: Hi @mozway, thanks a lot for digging so deep, but If I take the 1st dataframe from above, maliciously replace the index with df.index = [1,2,2], and call df.at[2,"B"], pandas does not raise an error but returns a series (I'm using pandas v2.0.2).

Comment: @gunnar then that might be an unwanted behavior. To come back to your original question ("*Why does df.at rise a KeyError with a MultiIndex while df.loc does not?*): **by design**, and trying to use an incomplete indexer *should* raise an error. If you need to get/set multiple values or use a partial indexer, use `loc`.

Comment: I agree. I guess, I was confused because usually the KeyError indicates that "a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys". In this case the key existed, but the indexer was not complete and thus insufficient. Let me sleep on that!

Comment: The dictionary analogy can actually be used to support this behavior. Dictionary indexing returns a **single** value. If you take `d = {(0,1): 'a', (0,2): 'b'}` then `d[(0,1)]` is valid but `d[0]` raises a `KeyError` ;)